# not able to hold scroll and thus uitableview cell in UITableview

Tags: iphone

i am aving a uitableview added programmatically.i am able to fill table view and decide number of row in table from array.i am able to scroll upto last data and can click the last uicell with data(obvisiously for didselectrowat:).
My problem starts from here:
on bottom of the table view i added a semi transparent image view.now if i scoll down for the last uicell and leave control from scroll to click(for didselectrowat:) that cell i am not able to click,it automatically goes down in the view and behind the transparent imageview.
So,how can i be able to scroll and hold data above the transparent imageview.may be image can help u understanding my problem:
[image]

i am not having mac right now with me..i can post my code the next working day?
thanks

Comment: have you set imageView userInteractionEnable property to YES

Comment: yes!however it doesn't matter.as i scroll down to access/click the last cell having data.and as soon as i left controll from scrollbar the last cell data again goes down the view.i want to maintain the state of scroll bar/or remain in the situation where it is, so that i can access the last uitableviewcell.

Comment: @Maddy: Pawan.Mangal's point is that it should **not** be set to YES (which is the default)... so set it to NO.

Answer (score 0):

```
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

The above should work. It'll transfer the touch interaction to the cell underneath.

If you really want to see the last cell clearly, your options might be:

1. Add dummy row at the bottom of the table. This will let the bottom
   cell come up and stay there.
2. Reduce the size of the table so that all of the table stays above the transparent image (that's not probably what you want).
3. If the table is scrolled all the way down... make the image hidden for a couple of seconds.

Comment: thanks!i will try!i have already try 2 option which worked for me.the transparent image is not clickable neither i want to make it.3rd option also a nice idea i will try this!i assume according to you the scrollable table last cell data can't be hold.i have to use some hacks as suggested by ou